# Unity Visual Scripting Variable

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a scene that has 3 buttons, one for each level. I made buttons 2 and 3 uninteractable and I want to make it so when you win the 1st you can start the 2nd etc... So I have unchecked the interactable box from the options of button2. Then I went to the script of my player and I have connected the following parts so when he completes the 1st level the button 2 gets to be interactible. But there seems to be an issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(This answer only applies if you were loading new scenes.)

Perhaps, the problem is that you can’t save a variable telling which levels are allowed. (Unless you do it through, an actual save mechanic.) this is because unity destroys all objects in a scene when loading a new scene. This removes all data stored in variables. You could get around this from using

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
```

this saves the gameObect variable you put in the parentheses through scene loading. You can attach a script that would store the variables to this, to save information.

If you can’t figure out how to get the variables from other scripts, use this:

```
 var newVariable = GameObjectVariable.GetComponent<scriptName>().variableName;
```

I see you were using visual coding, so if you can try and figure out how to find these methods in there, it should work.

If you want to use actual save mechanics, go to this link:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html/

Answer (score 0):

Set Variable need to receive a flow input.

Comment: Are you done with writing? This seems so ... incomplete. Would you like to make things clearer by using https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ? Or maybe by just using a few additional words? Or maybe punctuation? Something is missing.